Area of circle= area of triangle
Question 10:
"If the area of a circle is equal to the area of a triangle, which of the following must be true?
a) The radius of the circle is equal to the base of the triangle
b) The circumference of the circle is equal to the perimeter of the triangle
c) The radius of the circle is greater than the base of the triangle
d) The circumference of the circle is greater than the perimeter of the triangle"

Please show some of your work/attempts. Otherwise the question will likely be closed.

If there is no restriction to the type of triangle and what defines the 'base', then it seems that none of them need to be true. (I can think of counter-examples to all of these). For example, take a triangle with a really long base and a tiny height that has area 1. Then all 4 properties seem to be false.

Well, what do you think?  Do you know how the area of a triangle and circle are determined.  One thing determines the area of circle. What is it and how does it determine them?  Two things determine the area of a triangle.  What are they?  As the one thing that determines the area of a circle also determines the circumference there is a relation between a circle's area and circumference.  Is there any such relation between a triangles area and perimeter? You should know the answer to these and if not you should study and ask your instructor more.

Okay, Heres a hint.  Area of circle = $\pi \cdot \text{radius}^2$; Circumference of circle = $2\pi \cdot \text{radius}$.  Area of triangle = $\frac 12 \text{base}\cdot \text{height}$.  Perimeter of triangle = $\text{base} + \text{side}_1+ \text{side}_2$.  That should be enough to determine if any of those need be true.

Compare the isoperimetric theorem: among all closed convex curves with a given area, the one with least perimeter is the circle.  That is the opposite of d).

Take a right-angled triangle with base $1000\pi$ and height $0.002$ and a circle of radius $1$. Then the triangle and circle both have an area of $\pi$.
Then:

The radius of the circle is less than the base of the triangle.
The circumference of the circle is less than the perimeter of the triangle

Hence, none of the statements are necessarily true.
